# Why do Keras losses consider only the last dimension of the input arrays?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In the current `master` branch on the Keras repository, one can find this inside `losses.py`:

```
def mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/78e1f57c484da15466a34ed543a1cc4709617a2f/keras/losses.py#L17

Note how the mean is computed only along the last axis of the arrays `y_true` and `y_pred` due to the use of `axis=-1`.

Similarly, the TensorFlow implementation reads:

```
def mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
  return K.mean(math_ops.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6612da89516247503f03ef76e974b51a434fb52e/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L414

And the same is true for all other losses defined in the same files.

*Why is that?* (This is my question.) To my understanding, losses are scalars, so why are some array dimensions kept?

The following is just background and *not part of my question*.
The reason I stumbled across this is that I was trying to implement some normalized MAE in Keras, and without thinking more about this issue, I tried this:

```
def normalized_mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1) / K.mean(K.abs(y_true), axis=-1)
```

This results in `NaN`s, though, possibly (I am still investigating) due to me trying to divide an non-scalar array by another one.

(**Edit**: I know that my samples, which are images, have some all-zero rows and columns in the target, so that would induce a division by zero for these rows or columns. Computing means over multiple dimensions at once, that it, complete images which are guaranteed to be not all-zero, solves this immediate issue, but still this raises the question above.)

Comment: You are getting `Nan` because `K.mean(K.abs(y_true), axis=-1)` could be zero. So you should add some small value to this denumerator(e.g epsilon).

Comment: @Mitiku you are right, but unless I have a made a serious mistake, none of my samples (which are images) should be all zero. Some rows or columns could be all zero, though, which would in fact explain the observed behavior. Which, if my interpretation is correct, raises the question why Keras computes losses by one dimension and not by sample.

Comment: I't because you are using `axis=-1` argument. You are specifying to get mean over the last axis.

Comment: @Mitiku I know that :) (Please do not confuse my motivation for the question with the question itself.) The question (still) is, why does Keras do that in its own implementation of the losses?

Comment: can you clarify more: why is using the last dimension unexected? Wouldnt y be one dimensional as these are your predictions?

Comment: @KaiAeberli the data can have any dimension in TensorFlow - for example, images should be stored with two dimensions so that operations such as `Conv2D` "know" which pixels are adjacent to each other. Higher-dimensiobal data are easily possible as well, and have lead to confusion (or more) regarding the computation of losses before (e.g., https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25970)

Comment: could you reshape it to make it one dimensional, at least for the loss estimation? You would do this to both y_true and y_pred, so that they both becomes 1d. If only Conv2D needs to know about the 2D location, for error calculation you could just simplify no?

Comment: @KaiAeberli of course I could. I can also simply remove `axis=-1` from my calls to `K.mean` and be done. (I have done that.) But that is not the question I am asking: I wonder *why* Keras chose to explictly put `axis=-1` in the first place.

Comment: ok good point - not sure there.